# Glitch with updated nvidia drivers for Dual Monitor

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, nvidia-graphics-card

Same problem already happened once so I rolled back to the latest non-problematic version, but it's been months now and I thought to try gain. Still the same problem, so now I thought to ask for help rather than rollback to this, now very old, version.

Currently I use 266.58 version drivers for Windows 7 x64 and GeForce GTX 275. (Downloaded from the nvidia website) I have two monitors, Samsung SyncMaster 223BW (LCD) is primary and LG F900B (CRT, old but still works) is secondary.

The problem: when I turn off the monitors (both or just secondary) all of the windows that were on the secondary monitor get moved to the primary. This also occurs when I use Sleep. Again, in the old drivers this didnt happen, but now it does and is very annoying, requiring me to manually move the windows back to the secondary monitor (which I use for most of the windows).

I had no luck searching for this on google, but maybe somebody here will have a useful suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same thing, but if you ask me, this is not a glitch or a problem. Turning off a monitor gives the same signal as unplugging a monitor. Imagine you'd unplug your 2nd monitor, and all applications were still on it.

The trick I use it to very quickly turn off both monitors. There really is no other option. This is an intended function.

Also, when I turn on my monitors again, I turn on the primary one first, then wait about 1.5 seconds, then turn on the secondary, or else it'd register the 2nd monitor first, and go all crazy. You have to find your way of doing it.

Comment: Nothing happens if I turn off only primary...

Comment: Are these 2 different monitors?

Comment: Yes, I wrote that in the question.

Comment: I appologize, didn't notice. Sometimes, when monitors are turned off, they stil lsend a signal through the cable. This way, the computer still thinks it's connected, and does not interact with the monitor turning off. I again have the same thing with one monitor opposite to the other.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same type issue with driver 266.58   Every time I restart Vista it comes up on one monitor only.  I have to go through the nvidia control panel and windows display settings to get the second monitor back.  and then move things around my desktop again.  frustrating and this did not happen until I updated my nvidia drivers.